# Probability of being closest to each other

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Suppose there are $N$ red dots and $M$ blue dots uniformly distributed in a square region with side $S$. Each red dot finds its closest blue dot and each blue dot finds its closest red dot. What is the probability that these closest peers will be mutual? For example, if $N_i = \mathrm{closest}(M_j)$ then the probability that $M_j = \mathrm{closest}(N_i)$?

Comment: Closest in term of Euclidean distance I guess?

Comment: yes you are right.

Comment: Do you mean the probability that all pairs are mutual? Or that a certain amount of them are mutual?

Comment: $p=1$? ... why wouldn't nearness be mutual?

Comment: I actually need the ratio of this mutual case happening? Assume we find and match the closest red dot for each blue dot. Out of these total M red dots (some maybe the same) matched to blue dots, how many consider its matching red dot as the closest among all blue dots?

Comment: Not sure this is all that helpful but here's a related question (which asked for a different probability): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2363841/matching-red-to-blue-dots

Comment: Is there any reason you expect this problem to have a nice answer? Any context you could give might help us solve it.

Comment: Context will confuse things. But I use it in stable matching where the preference lists are defined based on the distance of other set users. I noticed that pretty good amount of users (50-56% with N=M) are matched to their first preferences mutually. I want to analytically prove it.